# How to index value in a String away

Tags: arrays, string, return-value

So for homework we need to find the exact `String` object in the `String array`. This is my code

```
public String get( int idx ){//IT HAS TO RETURN STRING AND TAKE A INT

    for(int i = 0; i<wo.length; i ++)
    if(wo[i]==wo[idx])
    return wo[i];
}
```

I tried casting to string but it didnt work. Does anyone have any ideas on what to do?

Thanks.

Comment: wo[i].equals(wo[index])

Comment: .equals is for only booleans

Comment: man, did you read your own question ? what language are you writing in ? where is `wo` defined ? what is the string that you have to return ? if you want other people to bother and help you - you should at least make the effort and phrase your question properly!

Comment: Ignoring that that's not how you compare two `String` objects, why would you iterate or compare them at all?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare two String objects with ==.

Use the `equals()` method.

Comment: Sorry I should of explained more properly. I'm writing in java. wo is a string array that is being filled in by input through scanner.